# Як правильно "політико-сатиричний" чи "політично-сатиричний"?

Tags: orthography

Як правильно написати що проєкт у жанрі політична сатира? *"український політико-сатиричний"*, чи *"український політично-сатиричний"*, чи взагалі *"сатирико-політичний/сатиро-політичний"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здається, усталеним прикметником є ***"політично-сатиричний"***.

Спочатку я думала, краще було б казати *"політико-сатиричний"* (від *політична сатира*) - за аналогією з *"політико-економічним"* (від *політична економіка*). Другий прикметник є у [Правописі 2019 р.](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) - п. 2.2.б § 40.

Однак я не змогла знайти прикладів вживання *"політико-сатиричного"* в літературі (шукала [тут](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&corpname=grac6&corpus-search-form=true)). Натомість, *"політично-сатиричний"* вжито, зокрема, у [таких реченнях](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac6&reload=&iquery=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&queryselector=iqueryrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=):

> У подальші роки Франко не менш активно працює над творами німецького поета, залишивши нам 23 переклади **політично-сатиричних** творів Гейне, серед яких — велика поема "Німеччина " і прозовий твір "Флорентійські ночі".
>
> ...**політично-сатиричний** роман Дж. Орвелла «Animal Farm», що вийшов під різними назвами («Колгосп тварин», «Скотоферма», «Скотохутір», «Ферма», «Рай для тварин», «Хутір тварин»)...

Звісно, відсутність прикладів вживання *"політико-сатиричного"* в одному корпусі не означає, що слово не має права на існування. Проте наявність прикладів до *"політично-сатиричного"*, думаю, схиляє чашу на користь останнього.